# Открытие и закрытие подменю при нажатии на одну и ту же кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Я сделал простое меню. При нажатии на блочный элемент, на котором написано "Кнопка" появляется подменю. Убрать подменю можно при нажатии на пустую область экрана. А как сделать так, чтобы оно убиралась при повторном нажатии на блочный элемент?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте метод [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

**Вариант 1** - *если нужно скрыть/показать меню при нажатии на кнопку*

```js
$(".test").on("click", function() {
  $(".menu").toggle();
});
```

```css
.test {
  width:100px;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  padding:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
  margin-top:10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">кнопка</div>
<div class="menu">меню</div>
```

**Вариант 2** - *если нужно скрыть/показать меню при нажатии на кнопку, а также если нужно скрывать меню при нажатии за пределами меню*

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != 'test' && e.target.id != 'menu') {
    $("#menu").hide();
  } else if (e.target.id != 'menu') {
    $("#menu").toggle();
  }
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menu {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">кнопка</div>
<div id="menu">меню</div>
```

---

**UPD: Вариант 3 на javascript** - *открытие меню при нажатии на кнопку, закрытие при повторном нажатии на кнопку или на область вне меню*

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let m = document.getElementById('menu');
  if (e.target.id != 'test' && e.target.id != 'menu') {
    m.style.display = 'none';
  } else if (e.target.id == 'test') {
    m.style.display = (m.style.display != 'block') ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">кнопка</div>
<div id="menu">меню</div>
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы также и при нажатии на пустую область подменю закрывалось ?

Comment: @user226023 а что вы понимаете под пустой областью подменю ?

Comment: @user226023, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36549967/4928642

Comment: А как будет выглядеть код на JavaScript Vanilla ?

Comment: @ПолосатыйТигр добавлен пример на javascript